# Appium REAL IOS Device app Testing:xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 65".

Tags: automation, appium, ios-ui-automation, appium-ios, appium-desktop

Appium Mobile Testing App on Real IOS device:
I am using Apple IOS 6 plus with UI automation enabled and my email id trusted. No idea what provisioning profiles or certificates i have.
I am stuck in mobile automation of the our app on real IOS device.

I have created a developer account on apple.
I have configured xcode and followed all the steps in the below link:

https://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/ios-xcuitest-real-devices/

Ran the build in Xcode and it was successful

[image: Ran the Build]

i am stuck at this highlighted step, i am getting connection was refused error.

[image: Got connection refused for this highlighted step]

I ignored the above connection was refused error and proceeded to run the appium inspector server with the following desired capabilities and found the following appium server error:

[image: Appium Inspector]

[image: Error Screenshot]

Could you please help me fix this and make me run the first mobile automation test.

Thanks,
Sai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note**: I was able to run my tests on real iPhone and iPad devices without a paid developer account.

I had used `agentPath` capability which points to WDA project path and `bootstrapPath` capability which points to WDA xcode project file where I had auto signed my profile.

Also I had set `xcodeSigningId` as hard coded value of `iPhone Developer`.

Can you try this steps and check if it works.

Comment: It worked thanks, and also now i am facing issue with typing by identifying by using an xpath field. could you please help me with this.

Comment: For typing issue, try finding the element by other then XPath and check if it works. I never use XPath. Also mark my answer as answered if your case is working fine now.

Comment: There is no element available other than xpath

Comment: Lets try another approach. Try clicking on that element which you want to type before typing. I think it should work.

Comment: Inorder for me to click on that element, that element is not being identified. Xpath is not working for that element, do you know if there is any other way to type the text field using coordinates , if yes could you please let me know the code for that.

Comment: Don't use coordinate. Try changing locator strategy to className or ID. Also try finding that element on an other parent element which has a proper ID e.g. textElm = parentElm.findElement(By.className("EditBox"));. This will work as I have came across plenty of such scenario.

Comment: I have only these attributes that are available for that element text box: type, value, label, enabled, visible, x, y, width, height and xpath as: //XCUIElementTypeApplication[@name="APP"]/XCUIElementTypeWindow[1]/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeScrollView/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther[2]/XCUIElementTypeTextField/XCUIElementTypeTextField

Comment: Can you raise another question for this with proper details and comment the question link here. I'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

You need a paid apple developer account to run tests on real devices, which need to be registered in your account's devices pool, otherwise you are limited to simulators. 65 can also occur if you have not installed carthage - 'brew install carthage'.

Also, another possibility is that you are trying to execute on an apple test device, which won't work. The easy way to spot this is to look on the backside of the device and see if it has a QR code in the lower part of the case.

Comment: Thank you Vivan you were right i was able to run the app on the simulator and not on the real device, we are now planning to buy a license. Thank you again